# What files are used when compiling Eclipse java applet and android projects?

Tags: eclipse, project-structure

If I put files not related to the code (e.g. photoshop source files, conceptual graphs, increments of code in another folder) in an Eclipse project, will those files be added to the resulting file after compilation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the java comipler translates the .java files to .class files which the Java Virtual Machine(JVM) can execute.The JVM cannot directly execute .java files and hence this step.

In eclipse, if "Project ->Build Automatically" option is set , whenever java programs are created/modified and saved in an eclipse project, the class files are automatically generated. During run-time(When the project is Run in eclipse),  your resources(files,images) are used to achieve whatever your program wants to do.

Hope it helps.